# How to install karma in windows - Eclipse?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am very new to this area.

**How to install karma in windows** - Eclipse IDE(Juno) to run jasmine.js framework test cases written for Backbone application?

What are the procedure should I follow while configuring Karma in windows 7?

Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, but contrary to Linux, Windows doesn't believe in the idea of "karma". Else they'd go bankrupt by now.

Answer (score 0):

1. -install node if not installed
2. -open commmand prompt to check if installed correctly npm -v
3. -run npm install -g karma
4. -Type in the command prompt: set PATH=%PATH%;C:...(path depends on your OS)... \AppData\Roaming\npm
5. -type karma should get the help menu